# How can I locate my R script files (saved on my computer)

Tags: r, rstudio

I loaded and worked on a dataset a few weeks ago and thought I had saved it in the right folder. Now I can't find it but I know I saved it on my computer. Is there anyway of finding the file location (that doesn't involve opening and closing hundreds of folders to check manually)?

Will appreciate the help. thanks

Comment: Have you done much work and/or saved any other files in that time? If not then a simple suggestion that may or may not work that doesn't involved any programming: File -> "Save As" and see which folder it opens.

Comment: Did you try using OS based search functionality

Comment: If those suggestions don't work you could try something like `list.files("C:/Users/you/DirectoryYouWantChecked", pattern = ".*\\.R$", recursive = TRUE)`

Comment: I unfortunately saved a few files today (in the right folder luckily). That's when I noticed that the other one was not there. I also tired the list.files("C:/Users/you/DirectoryYouWantChecked", pattern = ".*\\.R$", recursive = TRUE)   command and it show 0 characters :/

Comment: Did you update that first parameter to be relevant to you? Maybe just your user directory directly?  It will list *all* .R files.  Do you know what you titled the file? Or possibly what the title could be. You could add that information into the pattern parameter. (also when responding to people use @theirusername so that they get pinged)

Comment: @Dason I hadn't properly updated it. I re-did it now and was able to see the list of files, which unfortunately doesn't include the script I was looking for. I guess I made a mistake when saving it. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what platform you are on, but I'll assume Windows.  You can do a variation on Dason's suggestion:

```
Rfiles <- list.files("C:/", pattern = "\\.R$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

That will give you all the R files on your C drive.  If there are too many there to look through, you can put them in order of modification date like this:

```
info <- file.info(Rfiles)
info <- info[order(info$mtime),]
```

Now look at `info$mtime` to see all the date-times, and pick out the entries that cover the time range that interests you.  E.g. I see this with everything deleted except for dates in October:

```
info$mtime

...
[1882] "2017-10-01 08:52:33 EDT" "2017-10-01 08:55:55 EDT" "2017-10-01 08:57:13 EDT"
[1885] "2017-10-01 10:25:04 EDT" "2017-10-04 07:04:34 EDT" "2017-10-04 08:06:33 EDT"
[1888] "2017-10-04 14:49:55 EDT" "2017-10-04 14:49:55 EDT" "2017-10-04 14:49:55 EDT"
[1891] "2017-10-08 08:08:53 EDT" "2017-10-25 13:18:43 EDT" "2017-10-31 11:08:25 EDT"
...
```

So if I was looking for an October file, I'd print `info[1882:1893,]`.